# Passing arguments to bool Function from command line

Tags: c++, arguments

i'm new to c++ i tried to search the web for help, but has no sucess, 
I'm Trying to pass arguments to the `CreateProfileWithIProfAdmin` Function, i guess that the reason i fail to pass the args it's because it's a bool type function which accept only boolean values, however, i tried already to add `(int argc, char *argv[])` to `main()` and to the `CreateProfileWithIProfAdmin` Function,

as you can see down inside the function there's variables for szProfile, szMailbox etc. my goal is to pass those variable directly from the commandline with args1 args2 etc.

What i need to do to pass char args to the function?

I'm VERY new to c++ and really appreciate any help, thanks...

```
// Function declarations
bool CreateProfileWithIProfAdmin();


void main()
{

    CreateProfileWithIProfAdmin();
}


// The Function i want to pass args to.. specifically the 3 chars variables
bool CreateProfileWithIProfAdmin()
{
    HRESULT         hRes = S_OK;            // Result from MAPI calls
    LPPROFADMIN     lpProfAdmin = NULL;     // Profile Admin object
    LPSERVICEADMIN  lpSvcAdmin = NULL;      // Service Admin object
    LPMAPITABLE     lpMsgSvcTable = NULL;   // Table to hold services
    LPSRowSet       lpSvcRows = NULL;       // Rowset to hold results of table query
    SPropValue      rgval[10];               // Property structure to hold values we want to set
    SRestriction    sres;                   // Restriction structure
    SPropValue      SvcProps;               // Property structure for restriction

    char            szProfile[80] = {0};    // String for profile name
    char            szMailbox[80] = {0};    // String for mailbox name
    char            szServer[80] = {0};     // String for server name

    // This indicates columns we want returned from HrQueryAllRows
    enum {iSvcName, iSvcUID, cptaSvc};
    SizedSPropTagArray(cptaSvc,sptCols) = { cptaSvc, PR_SERVICE_NAME, PR_SERVICE_UID };
```

Comment: `main` must have the return type `int`, not `void`. Next, your `CreateProfileWithIProfAdmin` does not accept any arguments, `bool` or otherwise (it has a `bool` return type though). Apart from that it’s not very clear what exactly you want to achieve because your explanation contradicts itself.

Comment: *"i fail to pass the args it's because it's a bool type function which accept only boolean values"* - it returns `bool`, that's all. Look up functions in C++.

Comment: in c++ do i must to declare a type for a function? and if yes, does the bool is really needed in this case?

Comment: `bool func()` means `func` returns a `bool` to the caller. `void func(bool name)` means `func` is called with a `bool` and refers to that bool as `name`. `bool func(bool name)` means `func` takes in a `bool` and returns a `bool` to the caller.

Comment: I would suggest that if you're as new to c++ as your understanding of function return types and parameters suggests, the program you are trying to write here is a bit beyond your current capacity. You should devote some time towards learning at least a basic understanding of the language before taking on such a challenge.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Also a decent read: [A Tour of C++. Part one: The Basics.](https://isocpp.org/images/uploads/2-Tour-Basics.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you grab a book on C++.

```
bool callingThisFunction(const char * ptr1, const char * ptr2, const char * ptr3)
{
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc == 4)
    {
        char * executeablename = argv[0];
        char * p1 = argv[1];
        char * p2 = argv[2];
        char * p3 = argv[3];
        bool result = callingThisFunction(p1, p2, p3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is a bit of madness in doing what I wrote up there. It certainly is unsafe.

Comment: About the best you're going to be able to do with an answer to this question without writing a textbook chapter. Recommend adding two things: explaining what you are doing with `const` and why it's important, and use at least one of the parameters in the function as an example.